# array index error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in using **PHP** and getting the below error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in ListPopulator.php on line 123

When i did some search , i found that it may be due to the array index , that I have only `[0]` index  , but i couldn't get clearly how can i fix that

My code is as below:

```
$testObj = new Test();
$this->build_one_all_tests = array();
$this->build_two_all_tests = array();

$build_one_tmp_tests = $testObj->find_stream_build_multiple_platforms_failures_invalid_tests($this->product, $this->stream, $this->build_no , $this->platforms, $this->invalid_flag, $this->order_column, $this->desc);

foreach ($build_one_tmp_tests as $test) {   // line 123 where i got the error
        $test->crossed = false;

file_put_contents('/tmp/filename.txt', print_r($build_one_tmp_tests, true));
        $this->build_one_all_tests[$test->test_id.'_'.$test->platform_name] = $test;

}
```

And the array output as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test Object
        (
            [id] => 1646066
            [stream_id] => 606
            [build_id] => 9682
            [platform_id] => 7
            [test_id] => EditorsBrowserEditReference
            [idpath] => Editors/Browser/EditReference
            [result] => FAIL_WITH_CRASH
            [summary_path] => EditorsBrowserEditReference.html
            [log_path] => EditReference.txt
            [purelog_path] => EditReference.purelog
            [runtime] => 15
            [category] => Editors
            [started] => 2017-02-28 15:28:46
            [at] => 2017-02-28 15:29:01
            [host] => ies-esd-rhe5x64-07
            [display] => :277
            [owner] => aeshak
            [table_name] => test
            [stream_name] => waly_DRs_2016_1_Main
            [platform_name] => rhe5_64
            [build_name] => 2016.1_8
            [crossed] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: seems that actually you have 2 arrays:
the first with the only [0] field
and inside this another with associative fields.
You are trying to use offsets of the second array for the first array (which has only 0 field), that's why offset 1 cannot be found - it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Wow!  Did you name this function? `find_stream_build_multiple_platforms_failures_invalid_tests()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
$testObj = new Test();
$this->build_one_all_testss = array();
$this->build_two_all_tests = array();
$build_one_tmp_tests = array();
$build_one_tmp_tests = $testObj->find_stream_build_multiple_platforms_failures_invalid_tests($this->product, $this->stream, $this->build_no , $this->platforms, $this->invalid_flag, $this->order_column, $this->desc);
if(!empty($build_one_tmp_tests))
 {
   foreach ($build_one_tmp_tests as $test)
    {   // line 123 where i got the error
        $test->crossed = false;
        file_put_contents('/tmp/filename.txt', print_r($build_one_tmp_tests, true));
        $this->build_one_all_tests[$test->test_id.'_'.$test->platform_name] = $test;

   }
}
```

Comment: This answer feels like you are treating a bad case of facial acne by applying a ski mask.  Can we expose/correct the real problem?  @WaleedAly Can you confirm the error line is the loop, the ->crossed, or another line?   I don't mean to insult your intelligence - sometimes it is the little oversights that set us back.  It may also help to offer the long_named function to see what is happening.  When everything generally looks okay, we need to put things under a microscope.

Comment: I got the same error with the same result when i use the recommended new condition    if(!empty($build_one_tmp_tests))